# Where is trash in new Photos app?

Tags: macos, photos, trash

iPhoto had it's own trash, and when you've emptied it, files moved to the system trash. I cannot find this in the new Photos app. When I delete files, they don't appear in the system trash.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no Trash any more - instead there is Recently Deleted, same as on the iPhone etc. which will countdown 30 days before final deletion unless purged manually or recovered beforehand.

In OS X 10.10 Yosemite, you can access it from the File Menu > Show Recently Deleted. In OS X 10.11 El Capitan, there is no menu item, but it can be accessed from the "Albums" tab, where you'll find the recently deleted folder in the familiar shape of the trash bin of yore.

You exit, once finished, by clicking any other category, or if you don't have the Sidebar open, any Header - Albums etc.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, do you know how to set/edit location metadata?

Comment: That cropped up recently, can't actually be done directly - let me find the link...

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180288/how-to-add-a-location-to-photos-in-the-new-photos-app/180302#180302

Comment: FYI, Location Metadata editing is coming as a feature in OS X 10.11 / El Capitan. https://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-preview/ "Now you can add a location to a single image or to an entire Moment."

Comment: Nice one @FabianTamp I can't say it's before time ;)

Comment: Can see it only from the File Menu > Show Recently Deleted. Apparently the 'Albums' tab has no trash icon or folder (OSx Yosemite)

Comment: To purge deleted photos:  select the Recently Deleted album, cmd-A to select all photos, right click, select delete, and confirm the prompt to permanently delete.