# My Macbook storage is full even after deleting all my photos

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, photos, storage

So I only got my MacBook Air last year and I am travelling so am taking a lot o photos but I have a 1TB hard drive that I transfer the photos over to every now and then, my time machine also backs up to here. Recently I got a message pop up saying my start up disk was nearly full so I transferred all the photos over to my hard drive and deleted them all. It was still saying full even after I emptied my recycling bin and went through recently deleted photos and emptied that. Still no luck so I went through the steps to go onto my finder and computer and find the size of all the files to see where it was all being taken up and theres 49GB in my photo library and there is literally NOTHING in there! Its so frustrating because its now going slow and it gets super hot if I'm charging it whilst using it because its just too full. Please can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may find your answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180332/where-is-trash-in-new-photos-app).

To summarize there is no empty trash like there was in iPhoto. Deleted pictures are moved to a recently deleted album and then automatically deleted permanently after 30 days. They can be manually removed or recovered at any time during these 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try :
select "Secure Empty Trash" from the "Finder" menu.

IF still no Turn Time Machine off, and wait a while, it will start to delete what are called Local snapshots and so should free up the space the photos took.

Failing that try disk utility.