# Photos.app Sierra - Add a brand new location to the locations database?

Tags: macos, photos.app, geolocation

I'm adding locations to my pictures in Photos.app and I want to a location that isn't in the database.

The Google search I tired told me how to add known locations, but not unknown locations. The only thing that Photos offers me near by is the local police station.

Any clues how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking to change the geo location or just assign a label to the location that's already correct / embedded in the photos. For the first item - see here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180288/how-to-add-a-location-to-photos-in-the-new-photos-app

Comment: Thanks for the link - it looks like I'll have to put the long and lat in instead of the address. When I add the location information for places in the UK I can simply type the full address. For my Trinidad photos I can't - although it knew Caroni Swamp and some places in Port of Spain. Out in Arouca it only knows the KFC and the Police Station, which tells me something about my adopted kith and kin.